# I need a PHP regular expression to validate string format of 5 digits, one comma

Tags: php, regex, expression, validation

I have a huge PHP input box on a webpage. This input should only take 5 digit string separated by commas:

```
00100,00247,90277,97030,00657
```

notice the last one has no comma at the end.

Is there a regular expression that can do this? Since the input box is very large and can take 100+ of these items, I want to validate it on the PHP server side before the database is queried and those avoid any SQL Injection tries.

Query is only run if only 5 numbers and a comma in the sequence, except for the last one.
These are a state's public water system ID's by the way.

Comment: Have you looked at using `explode()`?

Comment: If you are not already doing so, I would also suggest that you also use the javascript regex to validate before sending to the server: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this will get the result you're looking for, though explode may be the better option.

```
/^(?:\d{5},)*\d{5}$/
```

This will only match 1 or more 5-digit numbers that are comma delimited with no spaces.

Comment: so in PHP, you'd use if(preg_match('/^(?:\\d{5},)+\\d{5}$/', $subject)) { ... }

Comment: Yep, exactly. I don't have PHP installed on this machine so I can't say for sure if PHP supports the ?: non-capturing group syntax, but it should also work without the ?: if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: This also matches `"00100,00247,90277,97030"` but OP wants exactly 5 numbers to match.

Comment: @anubhava: No, OP wants to test for 5-digit numbers separated by commas. "can take 100+ of these items"

Comment: This is what he wrote: `Query is only run if only 5 numbers and a comma in the sequence, except for the last one.` So I would interpret that as `num1,num2,num3,num4,num5`

Comment: I interpreted it as the numbers in the sequence need to consist of 5 digits followed by a comma "except for the last one."

Comment: That's how I read it, too: An unknown number of *blocks* (potentially over 100), each block consisting of five digits, delimited by commas.  So this regex should work fine--but I pity the user who has to *type in* all that data! :D

Comment: I've got processes the client can use to generate these 5 digit numbers. They are ID's for public water systems. They store these ID's in their LIMS (Laboratory Information Management Systems). I am mainly interested in protection from sql injection.

Comment: How to do for the following sequence "A,B,C,D,......,N" any one can help me. the value should be A-N only.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is user submitted data, your validation should be more flexible. What if the user accidentally puts a space after one of the commas? Or a line break gets inserted?

I realize you are looking for a regex solution but may I suggest using explode to create an array and apply a rule to each element. Having them separated into elements allows more flexibility when validating and storing:

```
$nums = explode(',', '00100,00247,90277,97030,00657');
foreach ($nums as $num) {
    if (!preg_match('/^\d{5}$)/', trim($num))) {
        // error!
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this will only match the first number.

Comment: You are correct. I've removed the regex as my main point is to suggest explode.

Answer (score 0):

I'd explode it and validate each string individually:

```
$input = '00100,00247,90277,97030,00657';
$input_array = explode(',', $input);
$is_valid = true;

foreach ($input_array as $number) {
  if (preg_match("/\\d/", trim($number)) != strlen(trim($number))) {
    $is_valid = false;
  }
}

print($is_valid);
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why you'd pick this approach?

Comment: Because I despise regex and try to avoid it, as I can't understand its syntax. I go with the intuitive route.

Comment: I'd rather read a single line, 20 char regex than 8 lines of PHP, personally.  But that definitely requires experience with regexes.

Comment: And that, my friend, is something which I do not have ;)

Comment: The OP was asking for a regex expression specifically. Plus saying "I don't use it because I don't understand it" may not be the best reason to go this route ;)

Comment: Well, I *did* use regex, but not to parse the whole thing. I just supplied my solution, which might be an alternative to a pure regex solution.

Comment: Nothing wrong with suggestion a different solution if the answerer feels it may work better and the problem is understood. That happens all the time on SO.

Comment: This solution will invoke the regex engine for every element, not to mention the overhead of trimming and array storage. On a simple case like this, going into the regex core only once surely will out perform this scenario.

Comment: But by how much ;) A millisecond isn't something I'd worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you rather need [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv):

```
while ($row = str_getcsv($fp)) {
    // $row is an array containing your digits
}
```

Comment: Change this to [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) and I'll bet you don't get downvoted.

Comment: Umm, ok, I wouldn't have thought that operating on a file instead of string makes this an inappropriate or bad answer, but here goes. (thx, btw)

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This regex matches a value having one or more comma separated 5-digit numbers:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{5}(\s*,\s*\d{5})*$/', $value)) {
    // Good value
}
```

It allows whitespace between the numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

`/^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$/`

**edit 1** noticed ridgerunner has the same answer, so disregard this.

---

**edit 2** some notes on performance.

### Failure analysis

**Backtracking** give back on failure:

`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$` gives back `,\d{5}`
`^(?:\d{5},)*\d{5}$` gives back `\d{5},`

**Post Backtracking** regressive topography checks:
(After backtracking give back, checks are to the right of the one that gave back)

`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$`  checks for `$`
`^(?:\d{5},)*\d{5}$`  checks for `\d{5}$`

Winner: **^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$**

**NON-Backtracking** regex's (using possesive quantifier `+`):

`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*+$` gives nothing back, fails immediately
`^(?:\d{5},)*+\d{5}$` gives nothing back  fails immediately

### Benchmarks

Using a string of 50 blocks of `\d{5},`.
The sample string is matched against each regex in a loop of 100,000 times.
Failure was induced at the end of the string, removed for a sucess test.

**Sucess:**
All took **1** second to complete a sucessfull run.

**Failure, Backtracking:**
`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})\*$` took **1.2** seconds **best**
`^(?:\d{5},)\*\d{5}$` took **1.6** seconds

**Failure, Non-Backtracking:**
`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*+$` took **.9** seconds
`^(?:\d{5},)*+\d{5}$` took **.9** seconds

### Conclusions

**Backtracking** - Put the smallest post-backtracking check
after the backtracking sub-expression. In this case, the
smallest is `$`.
In general, put the required expressions **ahead** of the optional ones.
Best **^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*$**

**NON-Backtracking** - It doesn't matter.
`^\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*+$` or `^(?:\d{5},)*+\d{5}$`